# How to rename column names in spark SQL

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with configurable column names eg

```
Journey channelA channelB channelC
j1      1        0        0
j1      0        1        0
j1      1        0        0
j2      0        0        1 
j2      0        1        0
```

By configurable I mean there could be 'n' channels in the dataframe.

Now I need to a transformation in which I need to find the sum of all channels something like

```
df.groupBy("Journey").agg(sum("channelA"), sum("channelB"), sum("channelC"))
```

The output of which would be :

```
Journey sum(channelA) sum(channelB) sum(channelC)
j1      2             1             0
j2      0             1             1
```

Now i want to rename the column names to the original names and I could do it with

```
.withColumnRenamed("sum(channelA)", channelA)
```

but as i mentioned the channel list is configurable and I would want a generic column rename statement to rename all my summed columns to the original column names to get an expected dataframe as :

```
Journey channelA channelB channelC
j1      2        1             0
j2      0        1             1
```

Any suggestions how to approach this

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To rename dinamically your DataFrame's columns you can use the method **toDF(scala.collection.Seq colNames)**, with whitch you can populate dinamically **colNames** with the original column names.

So you can populate dinamically a sequence like this:

```
val columnsRenamed = Seq("Journey", "channelA", "channelB","channelC")
```

and then call the method toDF:

```
df = df.toDF(columnsRenamed: _*)
```

The reason of `: _*` operator is to cast form `Seq[String]` to `String*`.

Answer (score 2):

It could also be renamed in the following ways, 
Say the input df is of the form inputDf: DataFrame with columns _1, _2.

```
val newDf = inputDf.selectExpr("_1 as x1", "_2 as X2")
* as -> maps to alias
```

***Other detailed answers could be found here:***
[Renaming Column names of a Data frame in spark scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592917/renaming-column-names-of-a-data-frame-in-spark-scala)