# Spark: DataFrame renaming columns and updating row values

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I want to rename a column using spark data frame and add a condition.

For example: I have a column "Code" which I want to rename to "Source Code" and I want to add a condition. When the values in the column equal "A" it should be renamed to "Agent" and when the value is "O" it should be renamed to "Other".

Comment: which language you are using?

Comment: @Natalia I am using Spark Scala.

Comment: Check this conversation [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592917/renaming-column-names-of-a-data-frame-in-spark-scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592917/renaming-column-names-of-a-data-frame-in-spark-scala)

Answer (score 2):

renaming column

```
df.withColumnRenamed("oldName", "newName")
```

updating value

```
val newColumnValue = df("c")... //some calculation
df.withColumn("updatedValue", newColumn)
```