# reading a subset of columns with spark_read_parquet

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I tried to read a subset of columns from a 'table' using `spark_read_parquet`,

```
temp <- spark_read_parquet(sc, name='mytable',columns=c("Col1","Col2"),
                                 path="/my/path/to/the/parquet/folder")
```

But I got the error:

```
Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The number of columns doesn't match.
Old column names (54): .....
```

Is my syntax right? I tried googling for a (real) code example using the `columns` argument but couldn't find any.

(And my apologies in advance... I don't really know how to give you a reproducible example involving a spark and cloud.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** This is not how `columns` work. When applied like this there [are used](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/blob/4974c8b2dd2a9789095790bd7ffb1b61b7266145/R/data_interface.R#L380) to [rename the columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35592917/8371915), hence its lengths, should be equal to the length of the input.

The way to use it is (please note `memory = FALSE`, it is crucial for this to work correctly):

```
spark_read_parquet(
  sc, name = "mytable", path = "/tmp/foo", 
  memory = FALSE
) %>% select(Col1, Col2)
```

optionally followed by

```
... %>% 
  sdf_persist()
```

If you have a character vector, you can use `rlang`:

```
library(rlang)

cols <- c("Col1", "Col2")

spark_read_parquet(sc, name="mytable", path="/tmp/foo", memory=FALSE) %>% 
  select(!!! lapply(cols, parse_quosure))
```

Comment: That's great. So, is there a way to load this into memory while reading the subset of columns?

Comment: This is where you use `sdf_persist` or if you want to restrict yourself to memory `sdf_persist("MEMORY")`. It is lazy, but otherwise will do the same think. However please keep in mind, that indiscriminate caching, might degrade performance more often than improve.