# Using a Map to rename and select columns on an Apache Spark Dataframe (Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Starting with a dataframe:

```
val someDF = Seq(
  (8, "bat", "h"),
  (64, "mouse", "t"),
  (-27, "horse", "x")
).toDF("number", "thing", "letter")

someDF.show()

+------+-----+------+
|number|thing|letter|
+------+-----+------+
|     8|  bat|     h|
|    64|mouse|     t|
|   -27|horse|     x|
+------+-----+------+
```

and a `Map`:

```
val lookup = Map(
  "number" -> "id",
  "thing" -> "animal"
)
```

I'd like to select and rename the columns such that ***number*** becomes ***id***, ***thing*** becomes ***animal*** and so on.

The renaming is covered in another Stack Overflow question: [Renaming column names of a DataFrame in Spark Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592917/renaming-column-names-of-a-dataframe-in-spark-scala), I'm sure there is a straightforward way to do the select at the same time that I'm not seeing.

I thought something along these lines would work, but get lots of type mismatches despite the input is a string and it works with a `Seq` instead of map:

```
val renamed_selected = someDF.select(
      lookup.map(m => col(m._1).as(m._2))
    ):_*
```

So the desired output is:

```
+------+------+
|id    |animal|
+------+------+
|     8|  bat |     
|    64|mouse |     
|   -27|horse |     
+------+------+
```

Thanks

Clarification on duplicate question flag: The question [Renaming column names of a DataFrame in Spark Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592917/renaming-column-names-of-a-dataframe-in-spark-scala) does not cover how to **rename and select columns at the same time**.

Comment: Clarification on duplicate question flag: The question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592917/renaming-column-names-of-a-dataframe-in-spark-scala does not cover how to rename and select columns at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way; Use pattern matching to check whether the name exists in the `lookup`, and give the column an alias if it does otherwise use the original name:

```
val cols = someDF.columns.map(name => lookup.get(name) match { 
  case Some(newname) => col(name).as(newname) 
  case None => col(name) 
})

someDF.select(cols: _*).show
+---+------+------+
| id|animal|letter|
+---+------+------+
|  8|   bat|     h|
| 64| mouse|     t|
|-27| horse|     x|
+---+------+------+
```

If you only need columns in the lookup:

```
val cols = someDF.columns.collect(name => lookup.get(name) match { 
  case Some(newname) => col(name).as(newname) 
})

someDF.select(cols: _*).show
+---+------+
| id|animal|
+---+------+
|  8|   bat|
| 64| mouse|
|-27| horse|
+---+------+
```

Comment: Thanks @Psidom - Realised my question wasn't 100% clear. I'd also like to drop the columns that are not in the map.

Would `case None => None` cover that?

Comment: If you only need columns in the `lookup`, you can use `collect` which will drop columns that don't match instead of `map`. See the update -

Comment: This works but I get a type checking error - any idea how to specify the correct types? 

`Type mismatch, expected: PartialFunction[String, NotInferedB], actual: Nothing => Column`

Comment: Figured it out: 

`
    val x: PartialFunction[String, Column] = {
       name: String => lookup.get(name) match {
        case Some(newname) => col(name).as(newname): Column
      }
    }

    val cols = dataOut.columns.collect{x}`