# Spark dataset alias column on-the-fly like for a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

May be a really silly question, but for:

```
val ds3 = ds.groupBy($"ip")
            .avg("humidity")
```

it is not clear how for a dataset, not dataframe, how I can rename the column like using alias on-the-fly. I tried a few things but to no avail. No errors when trying, but no effect.

I would like "avg_humidity" as col name.

Extending the question, what if I issue:

```
val ds3 = ds.groupBy($"ip")
            .avg()
```

How to handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`avg` does not provide an alias func you might need an extra `withColumnRenamed`

```
val ds3 = ds.groupBy($"ip")
  .avg("humidity")
  .withColumnRenamed("avg(humidity)","avg_humidity")
```

instead you can use `.agg(avg("humidity").as("avg_humidity"))`

```
val ds3 = ds.groupBy($"ip").agg(avg("humidity").as("avg_humidity"))
```

Comment: You meant if you execute `ds.groupBy($"ip").avg() ` ? @thebluephantom or you meant and exception?

Comment: When using the functions I note that we get dataframes again - I saw that a long time ago and in fact that does not appear to have changed. Disappointing.

Comment: ohh now I got it @thebluephantom

Comment: I am studying for a certification and thought I would check the DF vs DS. I see many issues with DS still. Just select and such works sort of, but AGGR mean a DF gotten, yes I know interchangeable, but plenty of work to do. Anyway I can change all the cols myself as I see there are limits top DSs that you confirm. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

[`groupBy(cols: Column*)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@groupBy(cols:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset) returns a `RelationalGroupedDataset`.

The return type for `avg(colNames: String*)` on it is a `DataFrame`, so by using `as(alias: String)` you're simply assigning alias to a new DataFrame, not to a column(s).

SO discussion about renaming columns in a DataFrame is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592917/renaming-column-names-of-a-dataframe-in-spark-scala).

Comment: Thx will look later. Confirms my view that DFs are easier.

Comment: So, I am back to where was eons ago. What advantage do I get from RGD? I prefer at this stage the DF by far.

Comment: _What advantage do I get from RGD?_ -- not sure what you mean. Its a class that defines group types and ops on them.

Comment: Oh well, we seem to every so now and again see i2i. here not, I think DFs are far handier in practice. Cheers and I did upvote u.

Comment: Cool thanks. I dont necessarily disagree... :))  Just saying that column names in DS have totally different meaning -- they are attributes of statically typed objects vs "column headings" in DF's Rows.

Comment: Bob's your uncle as they say down-under